# Какой узнать язык локализации телефона?

Tags: android, android-studio

Какой функцией проверить локализацию телефона (язык на котором ОС). Чтобы потом, в зависимости от локализации телефона, использовался определенный класс для дальнейших действий.

Comment: Стало яснее, внес правки в ваш вопрос. комментарии можно удалить

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Locale.getDefault().getLanguage()
```

Потом проверяешь `lang.contentEquals("ru")`.

Answer (score 6):

```
  public static Locale getCurrentLocale(Context context){
      if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N){
          return context.getResources().getConfiguration().getLocales().get(0);
      } else{
          //noinspection deprecation
          return context.getResources().getConfiguration().locale;
      }
  }
```